# Getting a null value while calling a function from a different class

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have a problem... I have 2 FrameLayouts, the first one is a ActionBar that could change and the second one is the screen layout that could change. Now I created my MainActivity like this:

```
public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity
{
    Dictionary<string, TriangleRegistryObject> TriangleRegistry = new Dictionary<string, TriangleRegistryObject>();

    //ALL FRAGMENTS
    public Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment;
    public Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment PreviousFragment;
    public Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment CurrentFragment;
    public int CurrentFragmentNum;
    public int PreviousFragmentNum;

    //ACTIONBARS
    public ActionBar_Setup actionBar_Setup;
    public ActionBar_Default actionBar_Default;
    //LAYOUTS
    public Intro_Add_Project IntroAddProject;
    public Shape_Selection ShapeSelectionFragment;
    public Shape_Formation ShapeFormationFragment;

    private string Direction;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        actionBar_Setup = new ActionBar_Setup();
        actionBar_Default = new ActionBar_Default();
        IntroAddProject = new Intro_Add_Project();
        ShapeSelectionFragment = new Shape_Selection();
        ShapeFormationFragment = new Shape_Formation();

        var TransActionBar = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        TransActionBar.Add(Resource.Id.ActionBarContainer, actionBar_Setup, "ActionBar_Setup");
        TransActionBar.Add(Resource.Id.ActionBarContainer, actionBar_Default, "ActionBar_Default");
        TransActionBar.Hide(actionBar_Default);
        TransActionBar.Commit();

        var TransLayout = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        TransLayout.Add(Resource.Id.LayoutContainer, IntroAddProject, "Intro_Add_Project");
        TransLayout.Add(Resource.Id.LayoutContainer, ShapeFormationFragment, "Shape_Formation");
        TransLayout.Hide(ShapeFormationFragment);
        TransLayout.Add(Resource.Id.LayoutContainer, ShapeSelectionFragment, "Shape_Selection");
        TransLayout.Hide(ShapeSelectionFragment);
        TransLayout.Commit();

        CurrentFragmentNum = 1;
        Direction = "Startup";
        ShowFragment(CurrentFragmentNum, 1, Direction);
    }

    public void ShowFragment (int CurrentFragmentNum, int PreviousFragmentNum, string Direction)
    {
        switch (CurrentFragmentNum)
        {
            case 1:
                fragment = IntroAddProject;
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = ShapeSelectionFragment;
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = ShapeFormationFragment;
                break;
        }

        switch (PreviousFragmentNum)
        {
            case 1:
                PreviousFragment = IntroAddProject;
                break;
            case 2:
                PreviousFragment = ShapeSelectionFragment;
                break;
            case 3:
                PreviousFragment = ShapeFormationFragment;
                break;
        }


        var TransLayout = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

        switch (Direction)
        {
            case "Forwards":
                TransLayout.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.slide_in_right, Resource.Animation.slide_out_left);
                break;
            case "Backwards":
                TransLayout.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.slide_in_left, Resource.Animation.slide_out_right);
                break;
        }

        TransLayout.Hide(PreviousFragment);
        TransLayout.Show(fragment);
        TransLayout.Commit();

        CurrentFragment = fragment;

        if(CurrentFragmentNum != 4)
        {
            var TransActionBar = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            TransActionBar.Hide(actionBar_Default);
            TransActionBar.Show(actionBar_Setup);
            TransActionBar.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            var TransActionBar = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            TransActionBar.Hide(actionBar_Setup);
            TransActionBar.Show(actionBar_Default);
            TransActionBar.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

And I created an ActionBar_Setup.cs as well. Here is the code of that fragment:

```
public class ActionBar_Setup : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

    public int CurrentFragmentNum;
    public int PreviousFragmentNum;

    public string Direction;

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.setup_nav_bar, container, false);

        CurrentFragmentNum = 1;
        PreviousFragmentNum = 1;

        Button btnBack = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnBack);
        Button btnNext = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnNext);

        btnBack.Click += btnBack_Click;
        btnNext.Click += btnNext_Click;

        return view;
    }

    public void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentFragmentNum > 1)
        {
            PreviousFragmentNum = CurrentFragmentNum;
            CurrentFragmentNum -= 1;
            Direction = "Backwards";
            mainActivity.ShowFragment(CurrentFragmentNum, PreviousFragmentNum, Direction);
        }
    }

    public void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentFragmentNum < 3)
        {
            PreviousFragmentNum = CurrentFragmentNum;
            CurrentFragmentNum += 1;
            Direction = "Forwards";
            mainActivity.ShowFragment(CurrentFragmentNum, PreviousFragmentNum, Direction);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I click on the button Next, it will call the ShowFragment() from my MainActivity. That works fine and all parameters are given the right way... But at the end of the function it crashes on the line: `TransLayout.Commit();` with the error:

> Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has
>   been destroyed occurred

Also I can see that the fragment has the value `null` and the PreviousFragment has the value `null`. This is caused by the 2 switch cases at the beginning, because the IntroAddProject, ShapeSelectionFragment and the ShapeFormationFragment are all `null`. That is weird, because I have given them a value in the OnCreate of the MainActivity.

**Can someone help me?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are newing a `MainActivity` object inside your Fragment. This is not possible in Android. Activities must be initialized by the OS

Instead, you can use the **Activity** property that is already part of the Fragment class and cast it to the *MainActivity* so there you could call the methods. Something like this:

```
(Activity as MainActivity)?.ShowFragment(CurrentFragmentNum, PreviousFragmentNum, Direction);
```

the **?.** is to prevent an exception in case the Activity is null because the Fragment has been detached.

Hope this works.-

**Note**: Remove your mainActivity object at the top of the class as you will not need it.

I meant this.

`MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();`

**Note 2**: Be aware that even though the above code will work and fix your issue this is not the best way to communicate between Activities and Fragments. Here we are coupling the **ActionBar_Setup** Fragment to be used only from the **MainActivity** Activity and one of the beauties of Fragments is that they could be reused.

To avoid this coupling one, one way to make it work is by defining an interface with the methods you want your activity to comply and then you make this implementation as part of the requirement of the Fragment. Then instead of casting to a specific Activity, you can cast to the interface.

I could update this answer later and add a sample if you want it.

Comment: A sample would be nice :)